# Google Calendar API - HangoutsMeet, not working anymore

Tags: api, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I've set up a service account from which i created events and added the hangout meet, so i could get the link to share.
It has worked till this morning and now i am receiving invalid conference type error, nothing has changed in my code.
Can you help me out?
This is the request that has always worked:

```
calendar.events.insert( {
        "calendarId" : 'primary',
        "conferenceDataVersion": 1,
        "resource":{
            "end": {
                "dateTime" : endDate.toISOString(),
                'timeZone': 'Europe/Berlin'
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime" : startDate.toISOString(),
                'timeZone': 'Europe/Berlin'
            },
            "conferenceData": {
                "createRequest": {
                    "requestId": randomstring,
                    "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

edit: i have removed "conferenceDataVersion": 1 and its working, when i tested it, it wasn't working without it. Has something changed?

Comment: Hi there @J0mk! I read that you solved the issue by yourself, could you please write the solution in an answer? It would improve this question documentation considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed "conferenceDataVersion": 1 and its working, no idea why. few weeks ago it wasn't working without it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to working now with or without conferenceDataVersion, and either as an insert event or an update event.  Is google messing with their APIs to eol hangout?